# Nested directives for dynamic UI

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a 2 level tab navigation with each sub-tab has dynamic UI content. I'm trying to have the whole UI created from JSON definition with main TABs array where each tab contain sub-tabs array. Each sub-tab contain UI elements such as text, combobox, radio button, multi-select list, etc...

I'm looking at this tab example and trying to combine it with dynamic content for the inner tab. Since I am new to angularjs I just hope to get some help to get me started.

http://plnkr.co/edit/QSvqd3hSqa8BUYU9eKaO?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org) for AngularJS, as it does much of the hard work around "creating a UI from JSON definition" for you. Here's a tutorial that creates a UI using JSON schema: http://metawidget.org/doc/reference/en/html/ch01s02.html